# How do I present a UIViewController modally when a button on it's parent view controller is tapped?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I'm having a little issue with an app I've completed. The problem is with a search view controller presented modally.

I have a search button that when tapped presents the `SearchViewController` modally.

I have 3 different controllers it can be presented from.

`MainViewController` > `CollectionViewController` > `DetailViewController`

This is actually how the controllers are in the hierarchy.

The results are always displayed on the collection view controller. Basically the collection view is refreshed and the remaining cells show are the result of the search.

**Searching from collection view controller:**

In the collection view controller, when the search is tapped. The search view controller is presented modally. Search text is entered and a list of matches is shown. When a row is tapped then the search view controller is dismissed and notifies the collection view controller using delegation the collection view is them refreshed with the results.

**Searching from detail view controller:**
In the detail view controller, when the search is tapped. The detail view controller is popped off the stack revealing the collection view controller. I use delegation to notify the collection view controller that the detail view controller was popped of the stack after the tap of a search button. Immediately the search view controller is opened making it possible to search as if we originally presented the search view controller from the collection view controller.

My issue arises when trying to search from my main view controller. Right now things are working but it doesn't have a very professional feel to it. Let me explain.

To get search working from my main view controller I use delegation. So in the method connected to the search button I perform this segue:

```
- (void)searchButtonTapped
{   
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"garmentsCollectionSegue" sender:nil]; 
}
```

**The protocol is defined in my interface file:**

```
@class VAGMainTableViewViewController;
@protocol VAGMainTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)mainTableViewControllerDisappearedwithTitleForObject:(NSString *)titleString;
- (void)searchButtonOnMainTableViewControllerTapped;
@end

@interface VAGMainTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<VAGMainTableViewControllerDelegate> aDelegate;
```

**In my preparation before segue I have this:**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
        [self setADelegate: [segue destinationViewController]];
        [[self aDelegate] searchButtonOnMainTableViewControllerTapped];
}
```

Here I set the delegate and also make a call to the delegate method, making the collection view controller aware of the button tap in my main view controller.

Finally in my collection view controller when the tap is detected a call to the method that presents the search view controller modally is made. Search view controller is presented.

In collection view controller

```
- (void)searchButtonOnMainTableViewControllerTapped
{
        [self searchButtonTapped];
}

- (void)searchButtonTapped
{
    VAGSearchViewController *svc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchPageSB"];
    svc.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:svc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

The search view controller notifies the collection view controller it was dismissed using delegation. This is when the querying and refresh of the collection view controller is done and the result of the search is shown.

```
- (void)searchViewControllerDismissed:(VAGSearchViewController*)searchViewController withTitleForObject:(NSString *)titleString
{       
    _searchTitleString = titleString;
    [self setObjects:nil];
    [self performQuery];
}
```

Ok so this works but it doesn't look professional because for a split second after the push to the collection view controller from the main view controller the collection view is shown before the search view controller is presented.

The feel I'm aiming for is a snappy one. So I'd prefer if the search view controller would be presented instantly.

Hopefully my detailed post give you an idea of what I'm doing.

There is a much more efficient way to do this. The problem is I can't figure it out.

Would appreciate some help

Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one thing did not push Collection view controller when search button is tapped.
After pushing modalviewControler if search done then you Call the delegate in MainviewController and  Then push collection Viewcontroller with no animation in DelegateMethod. its look what you want